# javascript range surroundContents() catch InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, jquery, getselection

i have a div with overflow:hidden containing mixed content html/text.
I applied a mousedown and mouseup event to this div container. If a user highlights content on mousedown, the selection is captured on the mouse up event.

Everything works perfectly, (until/or if) the user performs the following action:

The user presses the mousedown inside the div container, highlights specific content, then while the mouse button is pressed down moves the pointer outside the container and then releases the mouse button which call the mouseup event outside the div container.

i get this error:
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

what i want to achieve is the following:
if the mouse button is released outside the div container, i just want to keep what is still highlighted inside the container only. and if this is not possible, remove all ranges/selections/highlights.

i have read all the documentation on .getSelection() and invalid state errors and google everything trying to find a way to my result.

everything Ive read presents no way to catch the InvalidStateError or how to handle the selection to keep whats inside the div container.

here is my code example:

```
<style>container{width:120px;height:120px;overflow:hidden;}</style>



<div class="container">testNode text testNode text testNode text testNode text testNode text testNode text testNode text testNode texttestNode text testNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode texttestNode text</div>



<script>$('.container').on('mouseup', function(){    
            var sel = getSelection();
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            var end = sel.toString().length;
            var newNode = document.createElement('tmp');
            /*on this following line i get invalidstate error
            if mouse released outside the container div*/
            range.surroundContents(newNode);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
})
</script>
```

Comment: **UPDATE:** I found away to eliminate the invalidstateerror by getting the range content into a string and finding an indexOf(range value in string format) in main containers html/text. if the indexOf(range string) == -1 then do not wrap the content of the container with the new node. this eliminates the error. However i would prefer to get the content of the highlited parts in the div only. with the first selection attempt even if its over the borders

Answer (score 0):

```
container = $('.container');
containerString = $('.container').html().toString();
selection = range.cloneContents();
selectionString = selection converted to String();
containerSelectionString = selection append to div get      
$('.container').html().toString();
```

I worked out a solution and got rid of the range.surroundContents(newNode) if scrolled out of bounds. 
This solution gets the users selectionString , then compares the selectionString to the containerString. 
if the containerString has index of selectionString proceed as normal as first code above, 
else if the index of selectionString is -1 (none existent), then we know that the mouse was out of bounds so we take the selection append to a newly created div element, then we get our containerSelectionString. Now we know what the user selected from the container.

NOW!!

we take our containerSelectionString and check if its unique and exists inside the container if so, we can wrap the range. we test if the container string occurs only once as follows:

```
if containerString.indexOf(containerSelectionString) == containerString.lastIndexOf(containerSelectionString && containerString.indexOf(containerSelectionString) != -1)
```

now we know if the string is unique and exists.

Now its easy, we take our containerString and revamp like so:

```
containerString  = containerString.substring(0, containerString.indexOf(containerSelectionString)) + '<tmp>' + containerSelectionString + '</tmp>' + (containerString.indexOf(containerSelectionString) + containerSelectionString.length))
```

now we just populate container with the new containerString and then as in my case, the temp is styled to have a unique background color.. Thats it.

if the string turns out to not be unique, we just let the selection dissapear. There might be a way of getting the startindex from the selection or range then splitting the divtext at the start index and if the end index is higher work with the second part of string and match, or if the end index is lower work with the first part of the string, however for my needs this solution is fine, there is only a 10% chance the user will need to re select text if its not unique.

hope this can help you.

BTW! the get .getSelection() here is actually a little function i made incase you using this on a different browser here is the getSelection() function:

```
$.fn.getSelection = function() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        return document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
};
```

Code is below:

```
$('.container').on('mouseup', function(){  
   var divObject = $(this);   
        var sel = getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
        var end = sel.toString().length;

                divText = divObject.html().toString();
                var selHTML = range.cloneContents();
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.appendChild(selHTML);
                var testS = div.innerHTML.toString();
                var findx = divText.indexOf(testS);
                if (findx > -1) {
                    var newNode = document.createElement('tmp');
                    range.surroundContents(newNode);
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                } else {
             var testS = div.querySelector('.container').innerHTML.toString();
             var findx = divText.indexOf(testS);
             if (findx == divText.lastIndexOf(testS) && findx != -1) {
             var sindx = findx + testS.length;
             divText = divText.substring(0, findx) + '<tmp>' + testS + '</tmp>' + divText.substring(sindx);
                        divObject.html(divText);
                    } 
}
                   div.remove();
})
```